# What is the difference between hash encoding and vector embeddings?

Tags: encoding, hash, embedding

I read

```
 Hashing is the transformation of arbitrary size input in the form of a fixed-size value. We use hashing algorithms to perform hashing operations i.e to generate the hash value of an input
```

And vector embeddings pretty much do the same that they convert an input into a vector of fixed dimension. Trying to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Hash encoding can use any function which can convert any string to a random unique number but while creating vector embeddings we try to use domain knowledge and context in which the string might have occurred in the corpus.